# How can I clone a big stream with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, stream

I need to clone a RetriableReadableStream without consume it and to do this I found this way to handle it:

```
logo.pipe(new stream.PassThrough()) //logo is the RetriableReadableStream
```

This works just fine with small img, but if use bigger files looks like the operation takes too much time, bringing me to an infinite loop.

Do you know a way to clone streams in an async way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work thanks to this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-stream-clone

```
new ReadableStreamClone(streamFile);
```

I'm not fully sure about the clone of big files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).